Is $C^0[0,1]$ a closed subspace of $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ when equipped with the $L^{\infty}$ norm?
Let $C^{0}[0,1]$ be the space of all continuous functions on $[0,1],$ I'm wondering whether $C^0[0,1]$ is a closed subspace of $L^\infty[0,1]$ when equipped with the $L^{\infty}$ norm.
So let's take a sequence ${f_n}\subset C^0[0,1]$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^\infty[0,1]$ for some $f\in L^\infty[0,1].$ By definition of the essential sup, there is some set $Z\subset [0,1]$ of measure zero such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[0,1]\backslash Z,$ so at least I know $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]\backslash Z.$ But how about those points on $Z$ ? Can I modify the value of $f$ on $Z$ such that $f$ is continuous? Any help is appreciated!

The map $C^0[0,1]\to L^\infty[0,1]$, $f\mapsto [f]$ is an isometry with domain a Banach space (I'm referring to $C^0[0,1]$ with the sup norm), therefore its image is also a Banach space (and therefore a closed subset).

@SassatelliGiulio This is very inspiring! Thanks for your answer!
